# What cscope reference card do you use?

Tags: c, cscope

What is the standard/best reference card for [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) shortcuts/usage that I can print for quick reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of doing this, and its cheap, is to get the hardcopy man page for cscope and create a text file...for instance:

```
$ man cscope | col -b > cscope.txt
```

Or, to convert to ps file for feeding into Ghostscript:

```
$ man -t cscope > cscope.ps
$ gs cscope.ps -sOutputFile=cscope.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this (for default **vim** bindings; at the top is first access key - Ctrl+'\', and capital letter is second key):

```
         ^\ 
Symbol
Global
Calls to
Text
Egrep
File
Includes
calleD by
```

This quick reference card is sticked to my monitor here (*) for more than 2 years:

```
________________
|              |_
|              |*|
|              |-
|              |
|              |
----------------
      |  |
     /____\
```

Extremely cheap and useful.