# How to view some data in gvim without saving it first?

Tags: unix, pipe, csh, io-redirection

For example suppose I do a certain `man` or maybe a `grep`.

I want to see the results using `gvim` without the normal procedure of saving them first and opening the saved file [because I don't need the results once I view them]

I tried two ways, both the methods fail:

a)

```
man gcc | gvim
//opens a blank gvim window
```

b)

```
man gcc > gvim
//saves the result in a new file named "gvim"
```

Is there a way to do it?

---

Below is a copy paste of the first few lines of what I get using `man gcc | gvim -` or `:r! man gcc` :

(`N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE` is what the NAME looks like in `gvim`. I guess `^H` is some non-displayable character, because it is not being displayed here on SO)

> GCC(1)
>   GNU
>   GCC(1)
>
> NNAAMMEE
>          gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler
>
> SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS
>          gcc [--cc|--SS|--EE] [--ssttdd==_s_t_a_n_d_a_r_d]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those are control characters. Here's one way to "get rid" of it

```
man gcc|col -b| gvim -
```

Answer (score 2):

See this answer that I have given to a similar question on prior occasion on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267742/what-cscope-reference-card-do-you-use/2268377#2268377), in that case do

```
man gcc | col -b | gvim -R -
```

Which takes the manual page for 'gcc', pipes it to 'col' with a switch '-p', then pipe it into 'gvim' opening the file as read-only using the dash '-' as taking in input from the previous pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
man gcc | gvim -
```

Here

- `man gcc` writes its output to the
  stdout and
- `gvim -` reads its input from its stdin
  and
- the pile connects the stdout of man
  gcc to stdin of gvim

Comment: yes, it does display the `man gcc` in `gvim`, but the text is filled with a lot of `^H` characters.

Comment: btw, what does `-` sign after `gvim` do? can't find it in `man gvim`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try from within gvim:

`:r! man gcc`

Some more info [here](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/57727)

Comment: same as what happens with `man gcc | gvim -`, the text is filled with a lot of `^H` characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your PAGER & EDITOR variables set up correctly:

```
export PAGER=less
export EDITOR=gvim
```

Then you can simply hit 'v' while viewing the man page in less.

Comment: where do I look for these variables?

Comment: Environment variables are typically set in your shell's initialization file.  For bash, that's .profile or .bashrc.